# Export hive query output to multiple tabs in excel

Tags: unix, hive

When running: `hive -e "query" > mysheet.xls`, I am able to export the output to a new excel file.

Could you help me with exporting another `hive query` into already created excel file into different excel sheet? (not overwriting the existing file/data).

Is this possible with `hive query`?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using stdout redirect `>`.  That will always create a new file.  If you use the adding redirect `>>` that will add to your current file (not creating a new tab in Excel).

That said your query is probably creating a `csv` file which can be then opened in Excel.

If you are satisfied with your results I recommend generating multiple `csv` files via script and then merging it either with other script into one big excel file or use directly Excel to merge multiple `csv` files.

You can use multiple ways to merge it with Excel - one of the possible way is [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3230-excel-import-multiple-csv-files.html)